# Selenium Grid 2 Node can't Connect to Hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I've got a local machine with ip: 192.168.1.x. Windows 7
I've got a VM with NAT ip; 10.0.2.15 and host-only ip: 192.168.70.64 Windows 7

My hub setup is simple: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub`

My node setup is as follows:

```
java -jar c:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.x:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=9,platform=WINDOWS -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=c:\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe -remoteHost http://192.168.70.64:5555
```

My hub goes up, but when I start my node I get the output:

Node:

```
jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.178:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=9,platform=WINDOWS -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=c:\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe -remoteHost http://192.168.70.64:5555
May 07, 2014 8:09:08 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid node
May 07, 2014 8:09:08 PM org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest addCapabilityFromString
INFO: Adding browserName=internet explorer,version=9,platform=WINDOWS
Setting system property webdriver.ie.driver to c:\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe
20:09:10.049 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.55-b03
20:09:10.049 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
20:09:10.063 INFO - v2.41.0, with Core v2.41.0. Built from revision 3192d8a
20:09:10.311 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub
20:09:10.311 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
20:09:10.325 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
20:09:10.325 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
20:09:10.325 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
20:09:10.325 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@152dbbf
20:09:10.325 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
20:09:10.339 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5555
20:09:10.339 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@5c0f8f
20:09:10.339 INFO - using the json request : {"class":"org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest","capabilities":[{"seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","platform":"WINDOWS","browserName":"internet explorer","version":"9"}],"configuration":{"port":5555,"register":true,"host":"10.0.2.15","Dwebdriver.ie.driver=c:\\selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe":"","proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy","browser":"browserName=internet explorer,version=9,platform=WINDOWS","maxSession":5,"role":"node","hubHost":"192.168.1.178","registerCycle":5000,"hub":"http://192.168.1.178:4444/grid/register","hubPort":4444,"url":"http://192.168.70.64:5555","remoteHost":"http://192.168.70.64:5555"}}
20:09:10.352 INFO - Starting auto register thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
20:09:10.352 INFO - Registering the node to hub :http://192.168.1.178:4444/grid/register
```

Hub:

```
$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub
May 07, 2014 10:08:38 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid server
2014-05-07 22:08:39.272:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2014-05-07 22:08:39.303:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
2014-05-07 22:08:39.310:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4444
May 07, 2014 10:09:09 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy <init>
WARNING: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
May 07, 2014 10:09:35 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy isAlive
WARNING: Failed to check status of node: Connection timed out: connect
```

I don't know why the node is not connecting.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you ping the host machine IP from the VM? The `host` value in the configuration json is 10.0.2.15 for some reason.

Comment: I can ping from the VM to the host machine.  I can't ping from the host machine to my VM NAT (10.0.2.15) or Host-Only (192.168.70.64) adapter

Comment: This is a communication issue between the host and the VM and not grid specific. Resolve this first so you can communicate both ways (ping / access network shares etc); suggestions are to change network settings for the VM (Bridged, internal network etc), disable firewall, real-time protection etc.

Comment: Additionally the firewall is disabled on the VM for each domain.

Comment: Everything was working correctly except the network.  Thank you Faiz, once I changed it to bridged my tests popped right up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a difference in the way my network was setup at home vs at work.

> This is a communication issue between the host and the VM and not grid specific. Resolve this first so you can communicate both ways (ping / access network shares etc); suggestions are to change network settings for the VM (Bridged, internal network etc), disable firewall, real-time protection etc - Faiz

Answer (score 0):

You will have this issue when your Host and Node are in two different Domains. You may be able to Ping to nodes from server and vice-versa but if you are not set you machines to talk to each other over n/w then this problem will arise. 
We had this problem when our Grid Server was in Domain A and the node was not in domain at all. We had to pull the nodes as will into the same domain for Grid to talk to the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I have both Windows 7 machines

I have removed windows firewall on node machine

This solved my problem